# Make context available in Google Cloud function triggered by Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying this code in a Google Cloud Function, triggered by Cloud Storage, node 10.

I'm not sure how to make the context available.   `Event: ${context.eventId}`

I've tried: module.exports.getDevices(context) = getDevices;

I've tried: module.exports.getDevices = getDevices(context);

```
async function getDevices() {
    console.log(`  Event: ${context.eventId}`);
    const cloudRegion = '....';
    const projectId = '.....';
    const registryId = '.....';
    const iot = require('@google-cloud/iot');
    const iotClient = new iot.v1.DeviceManagerClient({});

    const parentName = iotClient.registryPath(projectId, cloudRegion, registryId);

    try {
      const responses = await iotClient.listDevices({parent: parentName});
  
      const devices = responses[0];     

      if (devices.length > 0) {
    console.log('Current devices in registry:');
      } else {
        console.log('No devices in registry.');
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        const device = devices[i];
        console.log(`Device ${i}: `, device);
    }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Could not list devices', err);
        }

}

module.exports.getDevices = getDevices;
```

Also, this works, but I want and async function like the previous one:

```
exports.helloGCS = (file, context) => {
  console.log(`  Event: ${context.eventId}`);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an async function, just declare it as such:

```
exports.helloGCS = async (file, context) => {
  console.log(`  Event: ${context.eventId}`);
};
```

If you want it to call a named function:

```
async function getDevices(file, context) {
  console.log(`  Event: ${context.eventId}`);
}

exports.helloGCS = getDevices;
```

Comment: Perfect, much better approach.